# System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException in WCF Service

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010

We have recently moved from VS 2008 to VS 2010. With that my applications are now running off of the .net 4.0 framework and MVC 2.0. After doing a little bit of conversion on my local machine to both the MVC project and the services project that gets referenced all is running seamlessly on my local machine.

I next copied the new MVC app over to it's virtual directory on my development machine and reassigned it to .net 4.0.

After that i copied the new services application over to it's virtual machine as well reassigning it to .net 4.0.

My problem arises whenever I call my service from within the new MVC application on the development server.  I receive the following error/stack trace:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : The requested service,
>   'http://localhost:9090/myservice.svc'
>   could not be activated.
>   See the server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.
>       Source : mscorlib
>       Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>       TargetSite : Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
>       Server stack trace:
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri
>   via, SecurityToken currentToken,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> ```
> Exception rethrown at [0]:   
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> ```
>
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at RugsDirect.Mvc.CreditCardAuthorization.ICreditCardAuthorization.AuthorizeCreditCard(CreditCardAuthRequest
>   request)
>          at RugsDirect.Mvc.CreditCardAuthorization.CreditCardAuthorizationClient.AuthorizeCreditCard(CreditCardAuthRequest
>   request)
>          at RugsDirect.Mvc.Controllers.CartController.SendAuthorizationRequest(PurchaseInformationModel
>   model)

I can go into IIS and browse this service no problem and everything appears to be in order on my config files and the mapping end points to eachother.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to solve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Billy

Comment: And did you look at the server's diagnostics logs, like you were told?

Comment: NO.  Where are they located exactly?  I have looked at the even logs without any real direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned that there is actually an issue with a dll that this service is calling.